# How to reference iOS UITextFields

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I am creating a crossword puzzle-type app, and am using the following code to make the grid:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
    [...]
    //we are inside 2 loops (puzzleRow and i), 15 rows (puzzleRow), 15 cols (i)...

    UITextField *inputBox = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:letterFrame];
    key = (puzzleRow * 100) + i;
    [inputBox setTag:key];
    [....]
}
```

Later, I want to reference the `UITextField` and get their value, check it against the correct answer, etc.

```
 - (IBAction)checkSolutionButton:(id)sender {
int i = 1;
for (id obj in self.Puzzle) {
    int len = [obj length];
    for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(j, 1);
        NSString *answer = [obj substringWithRange:range];
        int key = (i * 100) + j;
        UIView *userGuessSquare = [self.view viewWithTag:key];
        UITextField *userGuessTextField = [userGuessSquare viewWithTag:key];
        NSString *guess = userGuessTextField.text;
        NSLog(@"guess: %@", guess);
    }
}
```

}

self.Puzzle is an `NSArray` of strings (ANSWER1..ANSWER2,ANSWER3..ANSWER4) constituting a crossword puzzle's rows, dots are black squares. The `UIView` are holders for the `UITextField`, each `UIView` and its `UITextField` has an identical key.

Here I am stuck. I get a warning `Incompatible pointer types initializing UITextField with an expression type UIView` I thought it was a subclass?

```
 NSString *guess = userGuessTextField.text;
```

is a no go.

QUESTION:
How can I make a bunch of `UITextField`(s) and then access them and their values later?

(**EDITED** to include entire `IBAction` method).

Comment: If you are certain that the view return from `viewWithTag:` will always be `UITextField`, so you might explicitly cast it to `UITextField` class to silent the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the tags should be fine. To get the UITextField you should be doing this:

```
UITextField *userGuessTextField = (UITextField*) [self.view viewWithTag:key];
NSString *guess = userGuessTextField.text;
```

This will cast the UIView to the more specific UITextField, which is ok since you know you've used it. Make sure your tags start above 0 as well.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. The most helpful part was how to cast, actually, that was killing me.